# Vaadin project execution in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, vaadin

I get the following error. How can I fix it?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Servlet [com.gym.GymperUI$Servlet] and Servlet [MyUIServlet] have the same url pattern: [/*]. Related annotation information: annotation [@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(loadOnStartup=-1, initParams=[], smallIcon=, description=, name=MyUIServlet, value=[], largeIcon=, displayName=, asyncSupported=true, urlPatterns=[/*])] on annotated element [class com.mycompany.gymproject.MyUI$MyUIServlet] of type [TYPE]
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:518)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:419)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
>       at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>       at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you this:

```
Servlet [com.gym.GymperUI$Servlet] and Servlet [MyUIServlet] have the same url Pattern: [/].
```

This just means that you have two servlets which try to handle the `/` URL. So either remove the other servlet or make sure they handle separate URL's.